# How to use right subprocess Pclose in Python?

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, subprocess, popen

I did a script in Python 3.3 which does queries to a PostgreSQL database. I am using **subprocess** and **Popen**, and it works, but I am pretty new doing this and I think I do not have much idea of how it is actually working. My question is:

**Do I have to close anything after doing Popen?**

I read some forums and tutorials which say yes, but when I do a kill or other command to my query result, obviously, I get messages like, for example, this one:

> 'list' object has no attribute 'kill'

I tried with signals and killpg, any idea? These are two of my code's queries:

```
database_list = subprocess.Popen('echo "select datname from pg_database" '
                                 '| psql -t -U %s -h %s template1' %
                                 (bkp_vars['user'], bkp_vars['host']),
                                 shell=True,
                                 stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()

update_result = subprocess.Popen('echo "UPDATE pg_database SET datallowconn = TRUE WHERE   datname = \'template0\'" '
                                    '| psql -t -U %s -h %s template1' %
                                    (bkp_vars['user'],bkp_vars['host']), shell=True,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.readlines()
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Urgh, why on earth are you doing this instead of using `psycopg2`?

Comment: Because I do not have much idea, I guess. I am using those queries to make backups of a PostgreSQL database, and I copied the code from other pages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, this is a much better job for `psycopg2`, the Python interface to PostgreSQL, than for use of `subprocess` and `psql`.

Furthermore, if you're doing backups, you should be using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`, not messing with `psql`.

### How to get a database list

```
import psycopg2

# Replace connection parameters with those for your DB; see the psycopg2 docs
conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=postgres user=myusername password=whatever")

curs = conn.cursor()
curs.execute("select datname from pg_database;")
dbs = curs.fetchall()

print dbs
```

### Better use of `subprocess`

If you did have to do it with `psql`, you'd need to realise that [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) returns a [`subprocess.Popen` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects).

These *represent* the child process. You can use them to [wait for the child process to finish](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), to read child process output, etc.

Most of the time, you will instead be using the wrapper interfaces like `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.check_output`, which automate this and make it a lot easier in exchange for reduced flexibility. In your case, I think you want [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output).

`subproces` can be used to write `stdin` to an object, by passing a tempfile containing the desired stdin, or by directly writing to the stdin file handle returned by the `Popen` constructor. You shouldn't need to do hacks like `echo` stdin into a process opened via the `subprocess` module.

If you had to do this with `psql` you'd want something more like:

```
import subprocess

username = "postgres"
dbname = "postgres"

p = subprocess.Popen(
  args = ['psql', '-qAt', '-0', '-U', username, dbname],
  stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
  stdout = subprocess.PIPE
)
p.stdin.write("SELECT datname FROM pg_database;");
p.stdin.close()
dbs = p.stdout.read().split('\0')
print dbs
p.wait()
```

Note the use of the null byte as a record separator, so database names with newlines in them are parsed correctly.

Comment: Finally I am using psychopg2 and it is working great. Thank you for your time!!

Comment: note: using `p.stdin`, `p.stdout` sequentially may lead to a deadlock due to any of the OS pipe buffers filling up. Either use the pipes concurrently in a non-blocking manner or use `p.communicate()` that does it for you

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah, I carefully avoided mentioning that issue given that the small write is guaranteed to be smaller than any sane OS's pipe buffer, then we close stdin (forcing a flush) before reading. So it seemed reasonable to avoid in this particular case, but in the general case I absolutely agree.

Comment: @CraigRinger: you should use `dbs = p.communicate(b"SELECT datname FROM pg_database;")[0].split(b'\0')`

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian That makes sense. Thankyou - learn something every time :-)